# Create loss function thats takes probability in calculating

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, loss-functions, artificial-intelligence

I am training object detection, the output is 5 numbers, probability that something is in the box , xmin, ymin, xmax , ymax

What i am trying to achieve, is the "probability", to be scaled between 0 and 1.

I have tried numerous loss functions , fox example "mse", and adjusted MSE that reuturns

binary crossentrophy of 1st parameter ( probability )(classification) + MSE of other 4 parameters. (regression).

But the number has never been scaled beween 0 and 1.

Is it possible to create such loss function, or do i need to create another output for CNN that will act as classficator?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

To scale the probability number between 0 and 1, you can use a **sigmoid activation** on that output.

I don't understand what do you mean by "trying numerous loss functions", since the loss function will not change the output range of your network. In other words, it doesn't matter which loss function do you use, the range of the output neurons will be determined by its activation function.

Comment: i was thinking about sigmoid, however it would also scale t xmin,ymin,xmax adn ymax coordinations wouldnt it?

Comment: I don't know which framework are you using, but supposing that the vector `x` is your output, you can use `sigmoid(x[0])`to apply sigmoid only to the first output (the probability).